# Componentes principales

Tags: r

tengo un problema con un biplot en R. Sé que tengo muchos datos y seguramente es por eso, pero de todas formas necesito graficarlos a todos. Podrían decirme como editar las dimensiones del gráfico o como hacer para que se lea todo?
Gracias.

`whr2021= world.happiness.report.data`

`whr.pca = prcomp(whr2021[, -c(1, 2)][, apply(whr2021[, -c(1, 2)], 2, var) > 0], scale = TRUE)`

`biplot(whr.pca, cex=0.5)`

`fviz_pca_biplot(whr.pca, repel = T)`

[image: Biplot]